# Is it possible to add a dot in a variable name in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm using`console.log(value)` however when I use `console.log()` If I wanted to play around with stuff and make it do other things is there a way I can create a function like...

`var console.log = (function() { // something }`

Comment: As far as I know, you can't add a dot in a variable name. var name.log won't work.

Comment: Dot notation signifies a key in an object, not a normal variable name. So you could do this to overwrite the entire object: `window.console = {};` Or you could do this just to overwrite the function: `console.log = function() { /* something */ }` Which is equivalent to this: `console["log"] = function() {}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a wrapper for the `console.log` function and then only use your wrapper to write to the console:

```
function myCustomConsoleLog() {
  // do stuff with your arguments
  console.log(arguments)
}
```

Now instead of calling `console.log(vars)` you would make a call to `myCustomConsoleLog(vars)`.

Comment: ahh so I can still use `console.log()` here and pass through what I want into the `console` and it'll still act the same and I just add some other logic above that handles what I want?

Comment: Indeed - all the `myCustomConsoleLog ` is doing in the end is calling the original `console.log` - but now you can do what ever you want before/after calling it.

Comment: Cheers man! I didn't even think about this approach which is a lot better and easier. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! Happy coding.

Answer (score 4):

**You don't need to *declare* `console.log` again because it's already declared.**

In Javascript, `console` is a global variable. There is nothing preventing you from adding, editing or removing properties from it.

So yes, you can just assign a different function to `console.log` or whatever else you want:

```
console.log = function(foo, bar) { ... }
console.anotherProperty = { ... }
```

If however, you were trying to create a `foo.bar` variable that does **not** exist yet, you could do it in many different ways:

```
// first approach
var foo;
foo.bar = function() { ... };

// second approach
var foo = {
  bar: function() { ... };
};

// third approach
var fnBar = function() { ... };
var foo = { bar: fnBar };
```

See more at [Console API docs](http://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api) and [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible the way you are trying.

What you can do is create an object and add to it some objects:

```
var obj = {}; // we create an object where we will add the functions
obj.i = 4; // a value
obj.log = function() { }; // a function
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do the same, like:

```
var console = {log:function(){  }};
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do something like this:

```
var console = {}
console.log = "alert me!"
alert(console.log);
```

Is that what you meant?